# Confusion about declined flags

Tags: support, flagging

I've seen this happen a number of times, and have always been confused about it.

Last week someone posted a new answer on [Did Dumbledore know the last part of Snape's Unbreakable Vow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38097/did-dumbledore-know-the-last-part-of-snapes-unbreakable-vow)

> > So at this point, I don't think Dumbledore knew about the Unbreakable Vow because it hasn't been made yet. I do not find Dumbledore to be indifferent to Snape; I find that he is merely suggesting to Snape that only Snape can reconcile in his soul whether killing Dumbledore under the circumstances he is facing would be an act of murder or an act of mercy, and he is allowing Snape the choice to consider it as an act of mercy.
>
> Why couldn't Dumbledore simply kill himself? Would it have really been that difficult? I rather doubt it.

Null and I both flagged it as "not an answer".

If I look at my flag history, I see that my flag has been declined.

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

OK. I didn't flag it for technical inaccuracies - I flagged it because they were clearly (IMO) asking a new question instead of answering the existing one. Asking why Dumbledore didn't kill himself in no way answers the question of whether or not he knew the last part of Snape's unbreakable vow.

But, OK - a mod sees differently that me. No big deal.

*However* - the answer was still deleted by a mod (I have no idea if these actions were taken by different mods).

**Why was my flag declined, and then the answer was deleted anyways?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That was my bad. In the mod flag screen, the preview didn't show that it was a quote, so the visible part appeared to be answering the question.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the same thing happen back on [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64802/5184) too, but it didn't have a quote. (I swear I'm not going to go back and do this for every one. Just trying to understand how things work.) Is it just mods reconsidering it after reviewing it multiple times?

Comment: That one was two flags handled by two different mods, I couldn't tell you why one was declined.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.

Comment: Wow. Jon Skeet's bots (which as we all know, all diamond and most high-rep users on the network are) are now so advanced they pretend to have disagreements!